# how to decrypt each hash string from a text file using openssl_decrypt and output each line

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

i have a text.txt file which contains a list of encrypted passwords,
each line starts with the name then a seperating symbol and then the encrypted passoword.
the list looks like-

```
instagram-&&-aHJK7y9894ds==
facebook-&&-dKBHJ&^(8*==
somesite-&&-djahJHl*(&==
```

now i want to decrypt password from each line using the key which is included in the code.
to seperate the hash and name i use php explode() function and "-&&-" as the seperator which gives me this array as output

```
code to convert text to array of encrypted password-
<?php

$data = <<<EOT
instagram-&&-aHJK7y9894ds==
facebook-&&-dKBHJ&^(8*==
somesite-&&-djahJHl*(&==
EOT;

$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
foreach($lines as $line){
    var_dump(explode('-&&-', $line));
}
```

the output looks like-

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "instagram"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "aHJK7y9894ds=="
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "facebook"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "dKBHJ&^(8*=="
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "somesite"
  [1]=>
  string(12) "djahJHl*(&=="
}
```

Now the main question is how do i use openssl_decrypt() in combination with this to get each line decrypted.

Comment: Read about the difference between hashing and encryption [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-hashing-and-encryption/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i researched a lot about this problem tried the solution provided by @Edoldin in my question.
I searched the problem in PHP official documentation- [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiq1qOj8OL6AhXF8jgGHWQvD4sQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fdocs.php&usg=AOvVaw1UsUwn8H3kM3oq4DedlaRQ)
and OPENSSl documentations here- [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj07pCM8OL6AhXs8DgGHcC1DokQFnoECBUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Fbook.openssl.php&usg=AOvVaw1f2ViYAkzDf6ExVzvTKg46)

I got the solution by modifing and using this code-

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $parsed=explode('-&&-', $line)
    echo "user= ".$parsed[0]." pass= "
         .openssl_decrypt( eng_data($key, $parsed[1]) )
}
```

This is the Final solution i am using.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if "==" is part of your password encripted but if yes this should show your decrypted passwords

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $parsed=explode('-&&-', $line)
    echo "user: ".$parsed[0]." pass: "
         .openssl_decrypt( Your_params_to_decrypt($key, $parsed[1]) )
}
```

old text: "*You can not decrypt a hash, hashes are not bidirectional, in order to know if a password matches the hashed one you have to hash it but you can not get the unhashed string because it's not unique*"

Comment: they are not hashes but encrypted passwords bythe way , i know how i can decrypt that single password with openssl_decrypt() function, i want to decrypt them all using the script, thats the question

Comment: Well if you know that, then your question's title is wrong/misleading

Comment: your code is capable of getting output if the list only has one line , or a single line, it is not working if file has multiple lines